# windows 10 ignoring 100BaseTx FD setting, cable not the cause

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet, bandwidth

I hope you guys can help me with an issue I am facing for about 2 weeks since I got my new windows rig. I don't know why but windows does not recognize it's connected by a 100baseTx FD cable.

```
PS C:\Users\Max> Get-NetAdapter

Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
Ethernet                  Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller            7 Up           2C-F0-5D-0A-9E-D9        10 Mbps
```

I additionally verified that by putting 1 Gigabyte on my NAS and got a transmission speed of about 1 Megabyte a second.

---

Now to the crazy thing about all of that. I've connected my Linux notebook to the cable and checked the linkspeed with mii-tool and found the interface connected by 100BaseTx FD, just like it should be.

I already set up the adapter config in the device manager and double checked it via PowerShell. 100 mbps mit Full Duplex is configured, but Windows still thinks it runs with 10.

```
PS C:\Users\Max> Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty

Name                      DisplayName                    DisplayValue                   RegistryKeyword RegistryValue
----                      -----------                    ------------                   --------------- -------------
...
Ethernet                  Speed & Duplex       100 Mbit/s Full Duplex          *SpeedDuplex    {4}
...
```

Any further hints I can try?